# How to track folder/file except nio

Tags: java

Is there any useful folder/file tracker except nio? Why except nio? Because its giving the same output when i created and updated the file. I need more clear watcher to see all updates(create, update, delete).

Here below inside main:

```
try {
            Path trackFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\folder_to_watch");
            WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            trackFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);



            boolean valid = true;
            do {
                WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();


                    for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                        //WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();


                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                            String createdFileName = event.context().toString();
                            Date date = new Date();

                            System.out.println("FILE CREATED:  " + createdFileName +" "+ date );

                        } else if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY.equals(event.kind())) {
                            String updatedFileName = event.context().toString();
                            Date date = new Date();

                            System.out.println("FILE UPDATED:  " + updatedFileName +" "+ date);

                        }

                        else if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE.equals(event.kind())) {
                            String deletedFileName = event.context().toString();
                            Date date = new Date();

                            System.out.println("FILE DELETED:  " + deletedFileName +" "+ date);

                        }

                }
                valid = watchKey.reset();

            } while (valid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

### Thanks.  ------------------------

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If nio does not provide you with the expected results, please show your code where you are using it and people may be able to see why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

How about [WatchService API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) from `java.nio`? The type of changes (listed in [`StandardWatchEventKinds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html)) could be obtained from `WatchEvent.Kind<?>`